# How can I make my image stop repeating at a certain point in HTML or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am making a website using CSS & HTML for a project in my Advanced computers class and I cant figure out how to make a repeating image stop at a certain point (About 500px from the top maybe? Or at least below the title).

I will post a link down below to my Html and CSS, I am trying to make the llama's clip off when they hit the Horizontal line. I know a little JavaScript so if you could show me how to do it in JS that would be great too.

[Link](http://codepen.io/JustAnotherLostSoul/pen/wBLYLo)

Source:

```
<!--Beginning skeleton of this document-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<title> Meme Bunker </title>
<head>

   <link href="meme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>


<body class="img">
<div id='cssmenu' class="img">
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Gifs</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Dank Memes</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact Me</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h1 align="center" class = "color">Welcome to Meme Bunker!</h1>
<hr align="center" width="100%" />
<!--Title and such ends here, horizontal line is disabled for now-->



<!--The Table Starts Here-->

<!--Table ends here-->



<!--Here is the button-->
<p align="center" ><button align="center" class="custom" name="Button" type="button" onclick="location.href='http://i.imgur.com/6PlRXhI.gif'">
     Click For SuperPowers </button></p>
<!--It ends here-->
<br />
<!-- This is a horizontal line -->
<p class = "comicsans" align="center">
Welcome to my new website!<br />
I will be showing you some cool memes!
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
#cssmenu {
  background: #f96e5b;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10;
  margin: 10;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #blue;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: black;
  opacity: .85;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-center li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-center li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fb998c;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
    border: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
h1.color      {
    color: #000000;
}

div {
    overflow:hidden;
}

div img{
    position:relative;
    left:-100px /*or whatever you want. can change it with js*/;
    top:-100px;
}

body.img {
    background: url(http://s15.postimg.org/44gu6yl1z/llama.gif) left top repeat-y, url(http://s15.postimg.org/94eaewqon/llama1.gif) right top repeat-y;
    background-color: #CC0000;  

}

a:hover {
    background-color: #DDDDFF;
}

p.times {
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}

p.comicsans {
    font-family: comic sans ms;
}





/* Center classes */
table.cen{
    align: center;
}
p.center{
    align: center;
}
div.align{
    align-content: space-around;
}
/* End of other stuff */




/* Links go here */
a.test: link {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #C00;
}
a.test: hover {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #6F0;
 }
a.test: active {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #90F;
}

a.test: visited {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #FF0;
}
/* End of links */

/* Start of input attributes */
input.custom{
    color:#08233e;
    font: comic sans ms, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    padding: 14px;
    background: url("giphy.gif") repeat-x center #ffcc00;
    background-color:rgba(255,204,0,1);
    border:1px solid #ffcc00;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    cursor:pointer;
}

input:hover{
    background-color:rgba(255,204,0,0.8);
}

input:active{
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
}

input.save{
    background-color:#a7dd32;
    background-color:rgba(167,221,50,1);
    border-color:#a7dd32;
}

input.save:hover{
    background-color:rgba(167,221,50,0.8);
}



</style>
```

Comment: Create a div 500px and repeat the image inside it

Comment: I checked out the pen, and I see **NO llamas**. Liar.

Comment: sorry the link is http://codepen.io/JustAnotherLostSoul/pen/wBLYLo

Comment: Then where would i start my div tags kurt? because if i just add that in the css it will make my whole body and everything on the page 500px

Comment: @MatthewWise I believe Kurt said **Create** a div, that way the div will be 500px and not the body.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining a max-height: x-px; on a div that contains it, or on the picture itself

Answer (score 0):

add another div in your body and add the lamas background to that div. You may need to change your z-index depending on your other css.

```css
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
#cssmenu {
  background: #f96e5b;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10;
  margin: 10;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #blue;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: black;
  opacity: .85;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-center li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-center li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fb998c;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
    border: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
h1.color   {
 color: #000000;
}

div {
 overflow:hidden;
}

div img{
 position:relative;
 left:-100px /*or whatever you want. can change it with js*/;
 top:-100px;
}

.lamas {
 background: url(http://s15.postimg.org/44gu6yl1z/llama.gif) left top repeat-y, url(http://s15.postimg.org/94eaewqon/llama1.gif) right top repeat-y;
 background-color: #CC0000; 
 height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
}

a:hover {
 background-color: #DDDDFF;
}

p.times {
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}

p.comicsans {
    font-family: comic sans ms;
}





/* Center classes */
table.cen{
 align: center;
}
p.center{
 align: center;
}
div.align{
 align-content: space-around;
}
/* End of other stuff */




/* Links go here */
a.test: link {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #C00;
}
a.test: hover {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #6F0;
 }
a.test: active {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #90F;
}

a.test: visited {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #FF0;
}
/* End of links */

/* Start of input attributes */
input.custom{
 color:#08233e;
 font: comic sans ms, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
 padding: 14px;
 background: url("giphy.gif") repeat-x center #ffcc00;
 background-color:rgba(255,204,0,1);
 border:1px solid #ffcc00;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:10px;
 border-radius:10px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f;
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 cursor:pointer;
}

input:hover{
 background-color:rgba(255,204,0,0.8);
}

input:active{
 position:relative;
 top:2px;
}

input.save{
 background-color:#a7dd32;
 background-color:rgba(167,221,50,1);
 border-color:#a7dd32;
}

input.save:hover{
 background-color:rgba(167,221,50,0.8);
}



</style>
```

```html
<!--Beginning skeleton of this document-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<title> Meme Bunker </title>
<head>

   <link href="meme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   
</head>


<body class="img">
  <div class="lamas"></div>
<div id='cssmenu' class="img">
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Gifs</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Dank Memes</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact Me</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h1 align="center" class = "color">Welcome to Meme Bunker!</h1>
<hr align="center" width="100%" />
<!--Title and such ends here, horizontal line is disabled for now-->



<!--The Table Starts Here-->

<!--Table ends here-->



<!--Here is the button-->
<p align="center" ><button align="center" class="custom" name="Button" type="button" onclick="location.href='http://i.imgur.com/6PlRXhI.gif'">
     Click For SuperPowers </button></p>
<!--It ends here-->
<br />
<!-- This is a horizontal line -->
<p class = "comicsans" align="center">
Welcome to my new website!<br />
I will be showing you some cool memes!
</p>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Width for the class Lamas set to 500%? I think you mixed up the height and width. Shouldn't it be width:100%; height:500px;

Comment: sorry just a typo should be 100%;

Comment: Simple mistake to make, I have a working copy also but noticed your answer so thought I would see if the css matched. Since it doesn't I seen no point in having duplicate answers. Good work :)